# jsf h:selectOneMenu : redirecting to new page

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I'm using spring3.0, jsf 2.0 and richfaces. 
I have the following method in my Bean:

```
public String onChange (){
    String render; 
    if  (this.getItemValue().equals("project")){        
        render = "Page1"; 
    } else if (this.getItemValue().equals("version")){
        render = "Page2"; 
    } 
    return render; 
}
```

and in my xhtml page a 'h:selectOneMenu'

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{Action.itemValue}" onchange="submit()"
 style="width: 90px; height: 22px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.menu_project}" itemValue="project" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Version" itemValue="version" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{Action.onChange}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I would like to select an option in my comboBox list to redirect to another page.
When I did a debug, I checked that onChange method is well executed, but the new page is not rendered !!

Can someone give me any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate upon an ajax request, then you need to send a redirect.

```
return render + "?faces-redirect=true";
```

Note that your `onchange="submit()"` is superfluous. Remove it. The `<a4j:support>` already does the same.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, I tried this, but it didn't solve my problem. Methods are exeuted but the page is not rendered.